# What are these exploding things I keep running into in Resident Evil 4?

Tags: resident-evil-4-2005

These almost invisible lines explode when ran into. Any avoidance tips? And what are they (the lines)?  Been a while since I played. (Like 3-4 years!)

I am playing on the Xbox 360.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invisible lines are actually trip wires connected to land mines.

One of the more annoying parts of Resident Evil 4 and 5. Especially when you have a clumsy "fall over on the spot and get back up" animation.

My best advice is to keep an eye out, especially around your feet. It is especially easy to run into one around corners, unless your moving the camera around to get a look.

Comment: The best thing to do is to shoot either the string connected to the landmine or the landmine itself from a safe distance.

Comment: Are Ganados smart enough to avoid them too?(a.k.a : The Enemies that speak Spanish.)

Comment: I don't remember them setting them off. I think they can avoid them it might even ignore them for picking up collision

Comment: Tripwires only appear on a few areas in [http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/Tripwire](RE4), and I don't even remember them from RE5.